# bash script regex to remove email address

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Wonder how I can remove all the email addresses(multiples embedded in a line with space before and after from a script with bash script? I tried the following, but not success.

```
sed 's/.*/ &/;s/.* \([^ @]*@[^ @]*.com\).*//' $exportfile
```

Comment: Better add sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

For GNU sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/\S+@\S+//g'
```

For all seds:

```
$ sed -E 's/[^[:space:]]+@[^[:space:]]+//g'
```

Append the filename.

Comment: First, I want to parse a file and remove all email address from a file. Besides, sed does not have -r. I also tried -i -E. Non works.

Comment: @Lazyworm Add the filename to the end of the command. I am using sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2. You could try `sed -E 's/[^[:space:]]+@[^[:space:]]+//g'`.

Comment: The `-r` option and `\S` pattern are both GNUisms, the version with `-E` and `[^[:space:]]` should work with bsd's version of `sed` as well. @Lazyworm, what OS are you doing this on?